# CATransaction synchronize called within transaction while preparing seque

Tags: ios, segue

I have UITableViewController, when I tapped one cell I want to show UINavigationController with UITableViewController as modal view.

I have this function to prepare seque:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowTitles"]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;

        if (navigationController) {
            DataListViewController *dataListController = (DataListViewController *)[navigationController topViewController];

            if (dataListController) {
                dataListController.delegate = self;
                dataListController.viewTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"Titles", nil);
                dataListController.dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.titles];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I tap on the cell I get this error: CATransaction synchronize called within transaction.

What could cause that error?

EDIT:
it happens in this place in cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't notice that for the function dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: I have to register the class, so I did it in the viewDidLoad function:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```